# Occasional JVM crashes from FileDialog.open() deep in native code

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

What I am currently facing is an Exception Access Violation in some Eclipse applications we are running in a Citrix Environment on Windows 2008 server R2.

The call starts in `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open()`, which calls  methods in `org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetSaveFileNameW` and then goes down to native libraries. 
It fails with a `#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x68931bab, pid=9208, tid=7616` 
with `siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x00000008 0x68931bab`

Analyzing the created minidump, I end in the `thumbcache.dll`

```
thumbcache.dll!CThumbnailCache::CThumbnailCache(int)    Unknown
thumbcache.dll!ThumbnailCacheCreateInstance(int,struct _GUID const &,void * *)  Unknown
thumbcache.dll!CThumbCacheClassFactory::CreateInstance(struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
ole32.dll!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 1000  C++
ole32.dll!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppActPropsOut) Line 1917    C++
ole32.dll!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties)    C++
ole32.dll!CProcessActivator::CCICallback(unsigned long dwContext, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 1737 C++
ole32.dll!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation(ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties, HRESULT (unsigned long, IUnknown *, ActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesOut * *) * pfnCtxActCallback, unsigned long dwContext) Line 1630   C++
ole32.dll!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext(ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties, HRESULT (unsigned long, IUnknown *, ActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesOut * *) * pfnCtxActCallback) Line 1487    C++
ole32.dll!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 1377    C++
ole32.dll!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppActPropsOut) Line 1917    C++
ole32.dll!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 685   C++
ole32.dll!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppActPropsOut) Line 1917    C++
ole32.dll!ICoCreateInstanceEx(const _GUID & Clsid, IUnknown * punkOuter, unsigned long dwClsCtx, _COSERVERINFO * pServerInfo, unsigned long dwCount, unsigned long dwActvFlags, tagMULTI_QI * pResults, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn) Line 1334  C++
ole32.dll!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance(const _GUID & Clsid, IUnknown * punkOuter, unsigned long dwClsCtx, _COSERVERINFO * pServerInfo, unsigned long dwCount, tagMULTI_QI * pResults, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn) Line 332  C++
ole32.dll!CoCreateInstanceEx(const _GUID & Clsid, IUnknown * punkOuter, unsigned long dwClsCtx, _COSERVERINFO * pServerInfo, unsigned long dwCount, tagMULTI_QI * pResults) Line 157    C++
ole32.dll!CoCreateInstance(const _GUID & rclsid, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, unsigned long dwContext, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 110  C++
shell32.dll!_GetUIThreadThumbnailCache@8()  Unknown
shell32.dll!CDefView::CreateViewWindow3(struct IShellBrowser *,struct IShellView *,unsigned long,enum FOLDERFLAGS,enum FOLDERFLAGS,enum FOLDERVIEWMODE,struct _GUID const *,struct tagRECT const *,struct HWND__ * *)   Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::_CreateViewWindow(struct tagRECT const *,struct HWND__ * *)   Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::_SwitchView(struct IShellFolder *,struct _ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *,int)    Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::_BrowseToView(struct _ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *,int)    Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::_BrowseObjectInternal(struct _ITEMIDLIST_RELATIVE const *,unsigned int)   Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::_OnBrowseObject(void) Unknown
shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::BrowseObject(struct _ITEMIDLIST_RELATIVE const *,unsigned int)    Unknown
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::_BrowseObject(struct _ITEMIDLIST_RELATIVE const *,unsigned int) Unknown
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::_JumpToInitialLocation(void)    Unknown
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::_InitOpenSaveDialog(struct HWND__ *)    Unknown
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::s_OpenSaveDlgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)   Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallDlgProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcWorker@24()   Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@24()  Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCreateDialog@28()   Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalDialogBox@24()  Unknown
user32.dll!_DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW@24() Unknown
user32.dll!_DialogBoxIndirectParamW@20()    Unknown
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::Show(struct HWND__ *)   Unknown
comdlg32.dll!_InvokeNewFileOpenSave(struct IFileDialog *,unsigned short,struct HWND__ *,struct _OFNINITINFO *,struct HWND__ *)  Unknown
comdlg32.dll!_CreateNewFileOpenSaveInProc(unsigned short,struct HWND__ *,struct _OFNINITINFO *) Unknown
comdlg32.dll!NewGetFileName(struct OPENFILEINFO *,int)  Unknown
comdlg32.dll!_NewGetSaveFileName@4()    Unknown
comdlg32.dll!_GetFileName@8()   Unknown
comdlg32.dll!_GetSaveFileNameW@4()  Unknown
```

This continues in the `hs_err_pid` file:

```
C  [comdlg32.dll+0x3a3c9]
C  [swt-win32-3740.dll+0x7536]
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetSaveFileNameW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetSaveFileName(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OPENFILENAME;)Z+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open()Ljava/lang/String;+882
[..]
```

VM Arguments are:

```
jvm_args: -Dorg.eclipse.springextensionfactory.timeout=60000 -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic
```

System is:

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

```
OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 32 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 150912848k(141091384k free), swap 152959000k(142953452k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 19:09:58 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600
```

The trouble is, that the problem occurs infrequently. We are currently not able to reproduce the problem constantly. It just happens from time to time. 
My current guess is, that the `thumbcache.dll` tries to create an instance of the ThumbnailCache, which it is not allowed to do for some reason. But my knowledge in the windows area is pretty limited.
Does anyone have an idea where that problem might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to have fixed the problem was to exclude the executables of the DEP (Data Execution Prevention) in Windows (System-> Advanced ->(Performance) Settings -> Performance Options).

We had turned on "Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select" and had to add those programs to the DEP. No reported crashes for a week now. So I will add this as answer and update if anything changes.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=188317) bug report which seems to be very similar to what you're seeing.
It's marked as **won't fix**, however there is a workaround suggestion:

> I'm going to close this as "won't fix" which simply means that we aren't going to try to work around it in swt code.
>
> I have also added the following item to the eclipse 3.3 release notes:
>
> Opening File Dialog crashes eclipse (Vista only)
> On Vista, launching eclipse using -vmargs -Xmx[any size] can crash eclipse when the FileDialog is opened. The workaround is to use the default heap size, i.e. do not use the -Xmx VM args. See bug 188317 for details.

---

It says "Vista only", but by the time that has been posted, Windows Server 2008 R2 didn't even exist, so I'd give it a try at least...

---

Another comment in this bug report states:

> My error only happens when I open a FileDialog with the shell from a PopupDialog.

Is that the case in your program?

Comment: Thank you for the search. Yes, there have been various problems with that FileDialog in the past. Unfortunately this case doesn't match. Eventhough the workaround with the Xmx paramter points in the same direction. My FileDialog however fails (occasionally) in every Rich Client application we are running on that system. Disabling the Xmx parameter is just not an option for us either. So unfortunately the suggested workaround is not helpful. I am currently testing some windows DEP settings.

Comment: @Calon What do you mean by _"my `FileDialog`"_ are you using a custom implementation?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was not formulated clearly. I just identify myself with my programs ^^. No, it's always the standard SWT implementation `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open()`.

Comment: While the answer didn't help in my case, it is nice that you tried to help. The +50 were for attention and I got some. So +50 for you :).